# cant run rails new or bin/rails server successfully. creates bootsnap install and run error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows

```
Bundle complete! 15 Gemfile dependencies, 69 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
run  bundle binstubs bundler
rails  importmap:install
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/iseq.rb:60:in `fetch': No such file or directory - bs_fetch:open_current_file:fstat (Errno::ENOENT) 
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/iseq.rb:60:in `fetch'
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/iseq.rb:85:in `load_iseq'         
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'         
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/yaml.rb:4:in `\<main\>'
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'         
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/yaml.rb:58:in `init!'         
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/yaml.rb:38:in `install!'
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache.rb:26:in `setup'         
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap.rb:71:in `setup'
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap.rb:112:in `default_setup'         
from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:5:in `\<top (required)\>'
from C:/Projects/blog/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'         
from C:/Projects/blog/config/boot.rb:4:in `\<top (required)\>'
from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'         
from bin/rails:3:in `\<main\>'
rails  turbo:install stimulus:install
```

have tried uninstalling and reinstalling bootsnap also ran gem cleanup, still get the same issue

Comment: 1- try creating gemset 2- use the ruby 2.7 lower the current released version. 3- use rails version according. Then you should not be having an issues

Comment: yeah switched to ruby 2.7.5-1 worked properly, hoping i can install other versions of ruby without affecting this rails app

Comment: Sure, try that. If that works I will answer and then you can accept that will be useful for other people,

Comment: does your issue gets resloved ?